# Get react native client, firebase token

Tags: android, ios, facebook, firebase, react-native

I'm a react-native newbee, trying to build an app which will receive notifications from an app server. The flow will be like this: App server -> FCM Cloud -> App client(android or ios).

I've started with [1] and I'm trying to generate and get a device token to be sent to the app server for identification. However I'm getting an error:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const defaultAppConfig = {
   ...
};

var defaultApp = firebase.initializeApp(defaultAppConfig);
var defaultMessaging = firebase.messaging();  // -> here, messaging not found
```

Can someone help me figure out how to get a reference to the cloud messaging object, and get that token, eventually?

[1] https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2):

Firebase SDK is made for the web so some functionalities won't work as you expect them to work, also to use push notifications in your project you'll need to write some native code to ask for permission in the user device and import firebase messaging in Android and almost the same (but with a little bit more configuration, notifications certificate from Apple and of course a paid developer account) to run it on iOS.

I'll recommend you to use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) as they have a lot of very well writen documentations that will help you configure everything.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: For First: I am using expo app, running on my android phone (so no simulators/emulators). Just scanning a QR code will run my in-development app.

For Second: Thanks, I didn't know that!

I've run react-native-firebase and it says that the packager started.. but I have no clue on how to use it further. (how to make my app run - as in expo case)

Comment: @MititeluStefan then the problem should be 2nd, try react-native-firebase as the Firebase SDK is made for the web, and notifications systems differ from web to mobile

Comment: @MititeluStefan 'how to make your app run' is a too wide concept... I mean, your question was related with the error and how to get the token... If you read react-native-firebase docs they have a step by step guide for both, Android and iOS